# isset(($_GET['variable'] ) not TRUE anymore after AJAX submit?

Tags: 7, ajax

I have a variable e.g. for a search query which i save in the URL:

```
.../page?variable=value
```

I get this variable and save it as a global variable so i can use it in all functions of my file:

```
if (isset($_GET['variable'])) {
  $GLOBALS['variable'] = $_GET['variable'];
}
```

I use `isset($_GET['variable']` since not at every page call, this variable is set.

When the page gets rebuild with an ajax_submit function, e.g. because an AJAX button was pressed, the variable `$GLOBALS['variable']` is not set anymore.

It seems like that `isset($_GET['variable']` does not return TRUE anymore.

What does cause this issue?

Comment: did you tried the print_r($_REQUEST); check what value is getting set into $_REQUEST instead of $_GET

Comment: The AJAX request has its own variables which need not relate in any way to those on the page it came from. Is that the issue?